# Error posting to Node server with Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, postman

I am having trouble trying to hit one of my endpoints through postman. I'm new to Postman, so I don't know if my error is from improper Postman usage or my server logic.

Here is the post route and the require of another module I made

```
    var Post = require('./models/post')
    app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res, next){
    var post = new Post({
        username: req.body.username,
        body: req.body.body
    })
    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err) { 
            return next(err)
        }
        res.json(201, post)
    })
})
```

Here is the post module

```
var db = require('../db')
var Post = db.model('Post', {
    username: { type: String, required: true},
    body: { type: String, required: true},
    date: { type: Date, required: true,
        default: Date.now}
})

module.exports = Post
```

the file structure is nodeServer/models with db.js, package.json, node_modules and server.js in nodeServer and post.js in models

my Postman request and the error it returns look like this

[image: Postman Screen Shot]

There is more error message beneath what's shown in the picture, but it's all path/morepath/path.js kind of stuff and includes some of my system information.

Please help me solve this validation error!

Comment: The usual POST content type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try that format first.

Comment: @Tomalak Same 500 error and ValidationError

Comment: Have you looked at what actually goes over the wire? i.e. Chrome developer tools, inspect the request on the network tab? Does it look right there? Then it's not Postman.

Comment: @Tomalak I also hit it with this curl command   

curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST --data "{\"username\":\"dickeyxxx\", \"body\":\"node rules!\"}" localhost:3000/api/posts

but i get bash: !\"}": event not foudn

Comment: @user137717 Use single quotes around strings that contain double quotes: `curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"username":"dickeyxxx", "body":"node rules!"}' localhost:3000/api/posts`

Comment: What does `console.dir(req.headers['content-type'])` show if you put that before your `var post = new Post({`? Also, what body parsing middleware are you using before that route?

Comment: @mscdex 'json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only using `bodyParser.json()`, then you need to either also add `bodyparser.urlencoded()` OR select the `raw` option in Postman, then select `JSON (application/json)` in the dropdown next the content type buttons, and then paste valid JSON into the body textarea field.

Comment: the raw option with valid JSON did the trick. My problem for a little while was the valid JSON... thanks!